# Notepad++, replace "x" with a value from a list

Tags: notepad++

Basically what the title says, let me make an example.

```
this=X
that=XXX
those=XX
```

I want to randomly replace X with a value from a list for example, (1, 2 or 3), so that it becomes:

```
this=2
that=312
those=32
```

Note that I would prefer that there are no repetitions in the strings, although I can repair that later, if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

#### I want to randomly replace X with a value from a list

This is not possible using built in Notepad++ functionality.

You could write a script to do it.

There is a [python script plugin](http://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net/) for Notepad++:

> **Python Script for Notepad++**
>
> - Full programmatic access to Notepad++ features and menus
> - Full programmatic access to all of Scintilla features
> - Call other plugin menu items
> - Assign menu items, shortcuts and toolbar icons to scripts
> - Process Notepad++ and Scintilla events, direct from a Python script
> - Python console built-in
> - Full regular expression support for search and replace - script Python regular expression replaces
> - Start external programs and pipe the output direct to a Notepad++ document, or filter it, or simply to the console window
> - Full documentation for all the objects and methods

Source [Python Script for Notepad++](http://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

As DavidPostill wrote, this is not possible via Notepad++.

However, if the list of replacements and the list of files in which to replace is short, I'd use the following manual approach:

- first, replace `XXX`, because `XXX` is not part of `X` or `XX` (reversed, `X` is a part of `XXX`, and if you replace `X` first, e. g. with `foo`, then you will end up with `foo`, `foofoo`, `foofoofoo`.)
- then replace `XX`
- at the end, replace `X`

  test1=X
  test2=XX
  test3=XXX

`ctrl-a, ctrl-h`

search: XXX
replace: foo

```
test1=X
test2=XX
test3=foo
```

`ctrl-h`

search: XX
replace: bar

```
test1=X
test2=bar
test3=foo
```

and so on.

#### Counter example:

```
test1=X
test2=XX
test3=XXX
```

`ctrl-a, ctrl-h`

search: **X**
replace: foo

```
test1=foo
test2=foofoo
test3=foofoofoo
```

### Alternatives

#### Cygwin

the first alternative which comes to my mind is `Cygwin` because it's installed on my PC anyway.

Fire up Cygwin and use `perl`, `sed` or `awk` for replacement.

#### Powershell

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60065), you could use some PowerShell script along the lines of

```
(Get-Content test.txt) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "foo", "bar" } | Set-Content test2.txt
```

#### Batch

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35599346), you can also use Batch scripts, e. g.

```
@echo off &setlocal
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "search=%1"
set "replace=%2"
set "textfile=Input.txt"
set "newfile=Output.txt"
(for /f "delims=" %%i in (%textfile%) do (
    set "line=%%i"
    set "line=!line:%search%=%replace%!"
    echo(!line!
))>"%newfile%"
del %textfile%
rename %newfile%  %textfile%
endlocal
```